# How does Drupal determine the context in which to display the admin theme?

Tags: 7

One of the great things about Drupal 7 is the inclusion of an administration theme, Seven.

How does Drupal determine whether to display the administration theme or the site's theme?
Is it path-based (everything under /admin), or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now a hook for this: [hook_admin_paths()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7). As usual, the default configuration is in [system_admin_paths()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_admin_paths/7) but there are many other implementations in core, search for [_admin_paths](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/_admin_paths).

Comment: Oh that is awesome: if Drupal 6's motto was "there's a module for that", Drupal 7's should be "there's a hook for that". I was also interested in how I could check if the page I'm on is an admin path, but using your info I was able to find it:  [`path_is_admin()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/path_is_admin/7)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for using hook_admin_paths to display the advance help + user login pages in the admin theme.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_admin_paths(), 
 * to define which paths will be displayed in the admin theme.
 */
function objet_admin_paths() {
  $paths = array(
    'help*' => TRUE, // the advanced help module
    'user*' => TRUE, // User login screens
  );

  return $paths;
}
```